# hide columns dynamically in rdlc report shows blank column

Tags: c#, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have used a parameter to hide some columns in rdl report dynamically by passing a parameter 'ColumnVisiblity' as shown below

```
=iif(instr(Join(Parameters!ColumnVisibility.Value,","),"1")>0,false,true)
```

It will hide the column's values but it shows the column (blank column), how can I completely remove the column and arrange other columns.

Comment: plase use shrink method in each fields.

Comment: @JojiThomasEapen : I have used shrink method, but it will not hide remove the column from viewing.

Comment: if the value is empty u can make an a.visible=false. in the load method

Comment: @JojiThomasEapen , In c# code or in report designer?

Comment: in c# code, if u made shirnk. then inside the code u make a visible false , or u can do one thing in the design part u can make visible false. according to the value only make the control visible true..( both way u can do.)

Comment: In the visibility section I have used hidden: =iif(instr(Join(Parameters!ColumnVisibility.Value,","),"1")>0,false,true) the how do I set a.visible = false

Comment: it shows the value got hide , u didn't hide the controller ex textbox or label. give visibility false to these controllers..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144314/discussion-between-jobin-and-joji-thomas-eapen).